# Is there an glibc equivalent for MinGW's _aligned_offset_malloc?

Tags: c, gcc, c11

I'm using a 64 bits Linux machine, with C11 and _GNUSOURCE flag (and C++17 if necessary, but I'd like to keep it to C).

I need to dynamically allocate some data (variable size `X` from a few KBs to MBs, not necessarily a power of 2) that should be aligned to the smallest power of 2 greater than `X` (ie. `Y=2^k >= X`), along with some metadata `M` (a pointer, 8B).

`M` should be accessible given any pointer in the allocated range (w/o any variables/data-structures for book-keeping).

To do so, I encode `log2(Y)=k` in the address' msbs, that way I'm able to get the start of the data from any address by using a mask.

Right now, I'm using `posix_memalign`, which can only align the start of the returned pointer (therefore I can't put the metadata before the data if I want it to be aligned). 
Which means I have to allocate `Y + sizeof(void*)` bytes, and get the metadata with:

```
uintptr_t get_metadata_address(uintptr_t address) { // 'address' could be any address in the allocated range
    size_t k = address >> 48;
    size_t Y = (1 << k);
    uintptr_t start = address & ~(Y - 1); // works because start is aligned to 2^k by posix_memalign
    return start + Y;
}
```

That's a bit of waste (`Y` could be ~twice as big as `X`) and I'd like to allocate only the strictly required memory: `X + sizeof(void*)`, and access it like:

```
uintptr_t M = start - sizeof(void*);
```

So, here comes my question: MinGW seems to have [_aligned_offset_malloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/aligned-offset-malloc?view=msvc-170), which I could use to allocate `sizeof(void*) + X`, aligned with respect to the correct offset (8B).

Is there an equivalent function/way to do that for Linux ? using `_aligned_offset_malloc` gives me the "implicit declaration" error.

Thanks!

Edit: I'm aware that requesting such a large alignment may be bad due to internal fragmentation, but it's the only way I thought of to be able to get access to that metadata given only a pointer.

Comment: Do you actually need the offset feature? Otherwise, how about standard C `aligned_alloc` from stdlib.h? Should be available from gcc version 4.7.x somewhere.

Comment: I'm not aware of any such function.  Instead, can you simply put M after the end of the data?  Also, what benefit do you gain from aligning your data to such a large power of 2?  I can see why you might want to align it to a cache line (64 bytes or so), or to a page (4K), but why anything else?

Comment: Have you tested that the `_aligned_offset_malloc` on your other platform is actually more efficient? It may just be doing the same wasteful realignment that you are doing.

Comment: @Lundin I'm aware of `aligned_alloc`, but it's even worse than `posix_memalign` because it requires the size to be a multiple of the alignment (which is not the case for  posix_memalign).

Comment: @NateEldredge If I could do it, I would, but I have no way to know where exactly the end of the data is, given only the address pointer. (I have only the 16 msbs to encode any information I need).

Concerning your 2nd comment, actually I didn't test `_aligned_offset_malloc`, so I don't know how it would behave, I just stubbled upon it when looking for a solution.

Comment: @NateEldredge `what benefit do you gain from aligning your data to such a large power of 2?` The only benefit is being able to locate the start of the allocated segment given any address in it, thus being able to locate the metadata.

Comment: Well, by saying "no data structures", you've made life pretty hard for yourself.  For instance, this would be easy to solve by putting your metadata in a separate hash map keyed by the data address, instead of requiring that it be physically adjacent to the data.  At this point, I think the only way to achieve what you have literally asked for is to write your own custom allocator.

Comment: @NateEldredge It would probably need to use an interval tree (or a simple binary search tree since the intervals do not overlap) rather than a hash map since the look-up needs to be done on an address with an unknown offset from the allocated address. The tree nodes would need to store the allocated address, allocated length, and metadata, and be sorted by address.

Comment: Does it actually matter if the memory is wasted? Due to Linux memory overcommitment, it will only be wasting virtual address space until the pages are written to.

Comment: Another option is to use WINE's implementation of `_aligned_offset_malloc` for inspiration. WINE's implementation uses plain old `malloc` behind the scenes, as can be seen in [heap.c](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/master/dlls/msvcrt/heap.c).

Comment: I see, thank you all for your answers. I'll look into the `_aligned_offset_malloc` implementation - or if it's too complicated, I'll just give up since it works fine for now.